# How to merge two tables based off key table in Power BI

Tags: merge, powerbi, powerquery

I have 3 csv's feeding into power BI, two containing timetracking information from 2 different services and one containing a mapping from their names to their respective ID's, as shown in the following column headings:

1. {Timestamp, 7P_ID, time_tracked, Work item type, ... }
2. {Timestamp, ZD_ID, time_tracked, ticket id, ... } (they have a few dissimilar column headers)
3. {employee_name, 7P_ID, ZD_ID}

I want to make a table (or at least combine this data in some way) that combines these tables so I have the following headings:

{Timestamp, employee_name, time_tracked, Work item type, ticket id, ... }

Any thoughts?

Edit: for instance...

| Timestamp | 7P_ID | time_tracked | work item type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-02 | 333-3 | 90 | task |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

| Timestamp | ZD_ID | time_tracked | ticket id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-03 | 444-444 | 67 | 24601 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

| Employee Name | 7P_ID | ZD_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jeff Bozos | 333-3 | 444-444 |
| ... | ... | ... |

and I want...

| Timestamp | Employee name | time_tracked | work item type | ticket id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-02 | Jeff Bozos | 90 | task |  |
| 2021-09-03 | Jeff Bozos | 67 |  | 24601 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

But of course there will be multiple employees and each will appear multiple times

Edit 2: Alternatively, it would be just as good to append a 'name' column to my two time logging files using the key file, but this is also something I can't figure out how to do.

Comment: Adding some sample data would help

Comment: I've updated the post^

Answer (score 0):

```
  let
  T1 = 
    let
      Source = Web.BrowserContents(
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68212487/how-to-merge-two-tables-based-off-key-table-in-power-bi"
      ), 
      #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(
        Source, 
        {
          {"Column1", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(7) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}, 
          {"Column2", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(7) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(2)"}, 
          {"Column3", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(7) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(3)"}, 
          {"Column4", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(7) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(4)"}
        }, 
        [RowSelector = "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(7) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR"]
      ), 
      #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Extracted Table From Html", 
        {
          {"Column1", type text}, 
          {"Column2", type text}, 
          {"Column3", type text}, 
          {"Column4", type text}
        }
      ), 
      #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars = true]), 
      #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Promoted Headers", 
        {
          {"Timestamp", type text}, 
          {"7P_ID", type text}, 
          {"time_tracked", type text}, 
          {"work item type", type text}
        }
      ), 
      #"Removed Bottom Rows" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Changed Type1", 1), 
      #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Bottom Rows", {{"7P_ID", "ID"}})
    in
      #"Renamed Columns", 
  T2 = 
    let
      Source = Web.BrowserContents(
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68212487/how-to-merge-two-tables-based-off-key-table-in-power-bi"
      ), 
      #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(
        Source, 
        {
          {"Column1", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(8) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}, 
          {"Column2", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(8) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(2)"}, 
          {"Column3", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(8) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(3)"}, 
          {"Column4", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(8) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(4)"}
        }, 
        [RowSelector = "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(8) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR"]
      ), 
      #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Extracted Table From Html", 
        {
          {"Column1", type text}, 
          {"Column2", type text}, 
          {"Column3", type text}, 
          {"Column4", type text}
        }
      ), 
      #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars = true]), 
      #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Promoted Headers", 
        {
          {"Timestamp", type text}, 
          {"ZD_ID", type text}, 
          {"time_tracked", type text}, 
          {"ticket id", type text}
        }
      ), 
      #"Removed Bottom Rows" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Changed Type1", 1), 
      #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Bottom Rows", {{"ZD_ID", "ID"}})
    in
      #"Renamed Columns", 
  T3 = 
    let
      Source = Web.BrowserContents(
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68212487/how-to-merge-two-tables-based-off-key-table-in-power-bi"
      ), 
      #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(
        Source, 
        {
          {"Column1", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(9) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}, 
          {"Column2", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(9) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(2)"}, 
          {"Column3", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(9) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(3)"}
        }, 
        [RowSelector = "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(9) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR"]
      ), 
      #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Extracted Table From Html", 
        {{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}}
      ), 
      #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars = true]), 
      #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Promoted Headers", 
        {{"Employee Name", type text}, {"7P_ID", type text}, {"ZD_ID", type text}}
      ), 
      #"Removed Bottom Rows" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Changed Type1", 1), 
      #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(
        #"Removed Bottom Rows", 
        {"Employee Name"}, 
        "Attribute", 
        "Value"
      )
    in
      #"Unpivoted Columns", 
  #"T1+T2" = T1 & T2, 
  #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"T1+T2", {"ID"}, T3, {"Value"}, "T1+T2", JoinKind.LeftOuter), 
  #"Expanded T1+T2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
    #"Merged Queries", 
    "T1+T2", 
    {"Employee Name"}, 
    {"Employee Name"}
  )
in
  #"Expanded T1+T2"
```